# Compute Simple interest at x per annum.

Tags: education

I have a question asked in a previous exam, where to find simple interest for y years at **x per** annum instead of **x% per annum**. If I use (p * 3 * 40)/100 to compute the value, the answer gets wrong. The answer is given in a solution where the formula taken as (p * 3 *4)/100 without any explanation. The question is:

> The simple interest on a certain sum of money for 3 years at 40 per
> annum is half the compound interest on $2000 for 2 years at 10% per
> annum. What is the sum invested on simple interest?

What formula should I use? Also what is the difference between **x% per annum** and **x per annum** with this regard.

Comment: I think the actually meant "40%" when they made the question that way.

Comment: Do you know the answer to it ?

Comment: Or it could be a fixed interest amount, like a flat $40\$$ earning.. best guess

Comment: What does that even mean... interest is a return on investment, not the investment itself

Comment: @Spectre The answer is 1750. How?

Comment: @ParveezAhmed , did you try taking 40% ?

Comment: @ParveezAhmed , they must have said $0.40$ and not simply $40$, I think.

Comment: @ParveezAhmed it must be 4% simple interest rate not 40. Please see the calculation in my answer.